# The package system is broken. how do i fix it?

Tags: updates

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERF6w.jpg)

Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libnss-systemd: Depends: systemd (= 245.4-4ubuntu3.13) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.4 is installed
systemd-sysv: Depends: systemd (= 245.4-4ubuntu3.13) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.4 is installed

Comment: Try running `sudo apt update; sudo apt -f install`, and post the output. Use code blocks instead of images for output.

Comment: Systemd 245.4 = Ubuntu 20.04 (focal)

Comment: Those version numbers are old and long superseded. This usually happens when users (unwisely) disable the `focal-updates` and `focal-security` repositories. Enable both. Then run `sudo apt update`.